# automake dependency

Tags: autotools, automake

I have a **static** library called `libunikey.la`, and an app named `ibus-unikey` that links to it.

The problem is, whenever `libunikey.la` is rebuilt, `ibus-unikey` is not rebuilt, so the changes to `libunikey.la` don't take effect on `ibus-unikey`.

I want `ibus-unikey` to be rebuilt (relinked) whenever `libunikey.la` is changed, the way Makefile dependency does.

How to do it with automake, GNU autotools?

***_*__*UPDATE*__*_*__*_*___**

To make it simpler, the real question is:
**How could I make a rule to force a target to be recompiled when another target / or simply a file, is changed?** (with automake)

Comment: Can yo make a minimal example that shows this? What you're asking for is the default behaviour.

Comment: @awoodland: I've updated the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your starting situation was along the lines of `_LDADD = -Lpath/to -lthe_dependency`, so yes in that case you fixed it (for most situations) by using the path to the `.la` file.

The best option, though, is to use [non-recursive `automake`](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html), so that the `_LDADD` dependency is expanded properly in all cases.

Namely, let's say your binary is in `src/` and your library is in `lib/` — if your current work directory is `src` and you changed a file in `lib`, that will **not** cause the library to be rebuilt, and your binary re-linked, because inter-`Makefile.am` dependencies do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer my self, just post this answer for those in the same situation:
add a line to Makefile.am:

```
my_target_LDADD = path/to/the_dependency
```

It will solve the problem.